# Change data in react table dynamically

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-table

I am using "react-table": "^7.8.0"
the data for this table is being fetched from redux using useSelector.
but it always takes previous state and not the updated state.

```
const { structuredEmi } = useSelector((state) => state.form)

{
    structuredEmi
    <IntrestBasisTable headerData dataa={structuredEmi}/>
}
```

github gist for intrest basis table :

https://gist.github.com/rohit-rai-0101rm/ccfb0209b2696cb4dc9feafdc77efdab

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `useMemo` in your code?
Like this -> `const data = useMemo(() => dataa, []);`

If yes, let's try to remove useMemo.

Comment: it's getting updated thanks a lot.

Comment: could please drop a hint on why useMemo stops updating state??

Comment: it's because you put an empty array as `useMemo` dependencies. So data will never be updated after being mounted. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

[Hai Huynh Ngoc correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891960/19566421) that this is due to the use of the `useMemo` hook with an empty list, meaning that your `data` variable is never updated once initially set.

Although removing the `useMemo` hook will resolve your issue, this is **not recommended** when passing parameters to react-table's `useTable` hook. Doing so is potentially inefficient, as `useTable` will run its underlying code on every rerender of your component, regardless of whether the underlying data has changed.

### Recommended Solution

A more efficient solution would be to include your `dataa` variable in the array of dependencies passed to the `useMemo` call, thus correctly updating the whenever `dataa` has changed.

Line 55 of your provided gist should thus read

```
const data = useMemo(() => dataa, [dataa]);
```

See the [React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) for more information.